# PHP: Export a JSON file and catch it by JS

Tags: javascript, php, json

Got a php code:

```
<?php
 $date = date("Y/m/d");     
 echo json_encode($date);
?>
```

It exports a json file. But then, I wanna catch it by JS:

```
$.get("/your/url").done(function(data){
});
```

But my problem is - how can I know where the JSON file was saved (if it even was saved)?

Does the `echo json_encode($date)` exports a json file to somewhere? Or echo has nothing to do with that?

Thanks for any further help.

**Edit**: Anybody can help me?

Comment: echo json_encode simply export json data not a file..you should use fopen() and file_put_contents()

Comment: @RajeshPatel It exports data, okey so HOW to catch this data by JS?

Comment: what is your php url from where you are exporting json?

Comment: @RajeshPatel I don't have a json file. Should I make it? Or it's not necessary?

Comment: The response is passed to your callback function as the `data` parameter - what more do you need?

Comment: @CBroe Dear CBroe, would you like to make a full answer? I would upvote it and mark as the best answer. Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you actually just want to use a PHP date in the same page you generated from PHP? Then you just need ```<script>var my_date = <?php echo json_encode($date); ?></script>``` then any JavaScript on that page can see it.

Comment: @Patrickkx, Rajesh said pretty much the same thing in his answer already ...

Comment: @CBroe But how can I catch something by url `$.get("/your/url").done(function(data){
});` which doesnt actually exist?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn’t exist? Your PHP script did generate some output, no? // Stop thinking in “files” – you are dealing with HTTP here, and that doesn’t know anything about “files,” it only knows _resources_.

Comment: @CBroe Hmm. Ok. But tell me, at least, what url should I type there. Url to my php file? It's the index.php (main file of the project)

Comment: @Patrickkx - Yes! The javascript requests the url of the php file. The php file outputs JSON data. The javascript receives the output of the php file and then processes it - in this case, by parsing the JSON. It really is that simple..

Comment: _“But tell me, at least, what url should I type there”_ – the correct one …? How should we know? You said you “got a php code” – so where you got it, presumably in its own file? Then the URL to request that script file, of course.

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for help. Would you like to make a full answer so I can mark it as best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are doing correctly in php side but in jquery side i dont know if `$.get().done()` works or not

i have used it by this way and its working fine

```
$.getJSON( "url/yoururl", function( data ) { 
  console.log(data);

});
```

You can also use

```
$.ajax({
method:GET,
url:'url/yoururl',
success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
}
});
```

`console.log(data)` will return date which you have exported from php

Comment: But brother, I need to getDate with PHP and then export it into JSON and then use in JS :)

Comment: But in ur solution you are using getJSON in PHP. I don't have any JSON file :) I just take date object from server in PHP, store it in a variable and then I want to export this variable to JavaScript (by JSON or something else)

Comment: brother $.getJSON does not require json file it require only json objects so if you are exporting data from php then you should have a php file url pass that url to $.getJSON and it will work fine

Comment: `$.getJSON( "../index.php", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);

});` I have this in my JS file. This `$val = date("Y/m/d"); 
echo json_encode($val);` in my PHP file. Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't jQuery, but the concept is identical.

### 001-tmp.php

```
<?php
    $date = date("Y/m/d");     
    echo json_encode($date);
?>
```

### 001-tmp.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

function ajaxGet(url, onLoad, onError)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onload = function(){onLoad(this);}
    ajax.onerror = function(){console.log("ajax request failed to: "+url);onError(this);}
    ajax.open("GET",url,true);
    ajax.send();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onBtnClick, false);
}

function onBtnClick(evt)
{
    ajaxGet('001-tmp.php', onLoad, onError);

    function onLoad(ajax)
    {
        var rawData = ajax.responseText;
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
        byId('ajaxTarget').innerHTML = parsedData;
    }

    function onError(ajax)
    {
        // todo: add something useful here
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='goBtn'>Get data from PHP</button>
    <div id='ajaxTarget'></div>
</body>
</html>
```